# MyWebSQL on Windows: MySQL client library is not installed

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to set up [MyWebSQL](http://mywebsql.net/) on a Windows server machine. I set up Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.3, then deployed MyWebSQL.

Now, when I go to http:// localhost/mywebsql/install.php, I get the error:

> ✘ MyWebSQL may not work correctly with your environment.

Specifically,

> MySQL client library is not installed

Then, following the link, I'm looking how to install the library, but [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php), I read that

> In the official PHP Windows distributions from 5.3 onwards, MySQL Native Driver is enabled by default, so no additional configuration is required to use it. All MySQL database extensions will use MySQL Native Driver in this case.

So, what did I miss? Can anyone help?

Thanks!

R.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. I just had to add this to php.ini:

```
extension = php_mysqli.dll
```

The statement in the PHP doc that "no additional configuration is required to use it" is a bit misleading.